# How to see all fields exposed by SOAP api?

Tags: python, api, soap, wsdl, salesforce

I am trying to modify a salesforce api call by adding more fields, that exist on salesforce. I have a wsdl file with a targetNamespace at the top of the file and a soap:address at the end

```
targetNamespace="http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/MY_API_NAME" 
soap:address location="https://MYPROJECT.my.salesforce.com/services/Soap/class/MY_API_NAME"
```

Can I use these links to find what data is being returned? Similarly, are these links usable to look at all available parameters etc.?

Should I be looking at changing the WSDL to add the new fields to the complexType being pulled?

(For reference, I am using python and zeep to call this api in this line:

```
return client.service.XXXXXX(_soapheaders=self.soap_headers)
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this however by reading a WSDL I'm confident in my answer below.

I don't entirely know what you're asking about calling the web service, however you shouldn't need to regenerate the WSDL unless these are entirely new fields added to the object that's being returned since the last time the WSDL was generated.

For example if I have an SOBJECT called **WebServiceFields__c** with the following fields

- Id
- Field_A__c
- Field_B__c
- Field_C__c

  ```
  webservice static WebServiceFields__c example(String Id) {

      return [Select Id, Field_A__c, Field_B__c FROM WebServiceFields__c WHERE Id = :Id LIMIT 1];
  }
  ```

If I export this WSDL the entire definition of WebServiceFields__c  is created. The definition for **example** states the return is the complex type of **WebServiceFields__c**

I then have a requirement to change the web service to:

```
webservice static WebServiceFields__c example(String Id) {

    return [Select Id, Field_A__c, Field_B__c FROM WebServiceFields__c WHERE Id = :Id LIMIT 1];
}
```

This will not require a WSDL regeneration as WebServiceFields__c  didn't change.

Only the addition of new fields to the object will require a WSDL regeneration.